# extending group automorphisms

Tags: group-theory

For a field extension $E:F$, an automorphism of the subfield $F$ can always be extended to an automorphism of $E$. What is the smallest (or simplest) example of a subgroup of a group, say $H$ a subgroup of $G$, where $H$ has an automorphism that cannot be extended to $G$?

Comment: I expect the smallest examples are $H=C_2^2$ with $G=D_8$ or $C_4 \times C_2$. Then $H$ has an automorphism of order $3$ that does not extend to $G$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $G$ be a group such that, for any subgroup $H$ of $G$, every automorphism of $H$ can be extended to an automorphism of $G$. Such a group $G$ is said to be of *injective type*. This has beend studied. For example, $G=A_5$ is of injective type, but the binary icosahedral group $SL(2, 5)$ is not.

Reference: [Extensions of automorphisms of subgroups](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/glasgow-mathematical-journal/article/div-classtitleextension-of-automorphisms-of-subgroupsdiv/EC064595D369F67A473EF16A35543375).

Edit: Another example is that there are automorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}× \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ that do not lift to automorphisms of the group 
$\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}× \mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}$, in which it is embedded. For $p=2$ this gives the "smallest example".

Comment: injective type...a new word...

Answer (score 2):

Among the symmetric groups $S_n$ of all degrees $n$ it is known that $S_6$ has an automorphism that is not inner: an automorphism which does not preserve the cycle-type of the permutation.

Now consider $S_6\subset S_n$ for $n\ge7$. The outer automorphism of $S_6$ obviously can't be extended to $S_n$ for the above reasons.

Comment: thank you for your answer